# Use of exclude in Django aggregation

Tags: python, django

I have a model similar to this :

```
class Product():
     tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)

class Tag():
     slug = models.CharField()

class Transaction():
      product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
      store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Store()
```

I would like to know if there is a way to exclude some lines when performing an aggregation. For instance, i would like to know how many transactions are related to each of my stores, but i would like to count transaction with a product containing a particular tag but exclude the transaction that contain another.

For instance, let's say that i have a Coke Product whose tags are "drink" and "soda", i would like to know how to count transactions with a product that have "drink" tag but not the "soda" one.

I tried this, but this not working :

```
Store.objects.annotate(
    non_soda_transacion_count=Count("transactions", filter=Q(transactions__product__tags__slug="drink") & ~Q(transactions__product__tags__slug="soda")
)
```

Do you have any clue ?

I am using Django 2.2.13

Comment: Did u try ! instead of ~

Comment: I probably miss something.. but you have "drink" in each part of Q objects. Is it normal ?

Comment: @EricMartin there was a typo indeed. I edited my post. Thanks !
@PriyanshuPanwar  `!` is not a python unarary operator so this won't work. And it's not mentioned in the `Q` doc.

Comment: Rémi, i try hard cause i find the topic useful. But i can't find a good answer. The only oneliner is to add a field in the product model : isOnlySoda. Which is ugly ! i think you should make a separate query to get your count.